# Remove corrupt revisions on SVN

Tags: svn, revision

Want to remove corrupt revisions on SVN. Try to dump revisions from 1-5133 after that 5847 to head but when I want to import dump file into the new repo below error appear!

```
svnadmin create /svn/newrepo

svnadmin dump -r1:5132 /svn/oldrepo > /tmp/dumpfile 

svnadmin dump --incremental -r5847:HEAD /svn/oldrepo >> /tmp/dumpfile

svnadmin load /svn/newrepo < /tmp/dumpfile

<<< Started new transaction, based on original revision 5850 * editing path : branches/15 ...svnadmin: E160013: File not found: transaction '5134-3ym', path '/branches/15'
```

Do you have scripts or commands let me get ride of corrupted revisions?

FYI: Here is the list of corrupted revisions:

```
* Error verifying revision 5133.
* Error verifying revision 5134.
* Error verifying revision 5135.
* Error verifying revision 5136.
* Error verifying revision 5137.
* Error verifying revision 5138.
* Error verifying revision 5139.
* Error verifying revision 5140.
* Error verifying revision 5141.
* Error verifying revision 5142.
* Error verifying revision 5143.
* Error verifying revision 5144.
* Error verifying revision 5145.
* Error verifying revision 5146.
* Error verifying revision 5148.
* Error verifying revision 5149.
* Error verifying revision 5150.
* Error verifying revision 5151.
* Error verifying revision 5152.
* Error verifying revision 5153.
* Error verifying revision 5154.
* Error verifying revision 5155.
* Error verifying revision 5156.
* Error verifying revision 5157.
* Error verifying revision 5158.
* Error verifying revision 5160.
* Error verifying revision 5161.
* Error verifying revision 5162.
* Error verifying revision 5163.
* Error verifying revision 5164.
* Error verifying revision 5192.
* Error verifying revision 5193.
* Error verifying revision 5194.
* Error verifying revision 5234.
* Error verifying revision 5235.
* Error verifying revision 5236.
* Error verifying revision 5305.
* Error verifying revision 5317.
* Error verifying revision 5321.
* Error verifying revision 5474.
* Error verifying revision 5531.
* Error verifying revision 5595.
* Error verifying revision 5632.
* Error verifying revision 5681.
* Error verifying revision 5722.
* Error verifying revision 5724.
* Error verifying revision 5820.
* Error verifying revision 5845.
* Error verifying revision 5846.
```

Any recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to *remove* corrupted revisions, you need to replace them with an empty revision. This manual repair is a complex operation that may require re-creating the repository and using svnadmin dump and load to replace broken revisions with a placeholder 'padding' revision. Therefore, backup restore is the best recovery option.

> <<< Started new transaction, based on original revision **5850** * editing
>   path : branches/15 ...svnadmin: **E160013: File not found: transaction
>   '5134-3ym', path '/branches/15'**

This error means that you also need to replace revision r5850 from the broken repository with an empty revision. The problem is that r5850 (and I guess many others, too) depend on several revisions you remove/replace. Therefore, r r5850 cannot be loaded.